# SQS - Reduce Max Message Size of a non empty queue

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

I'm considering reducing the Max Message Size of a queue we're using on SQS.

What would happen to the messages on the queue already?
Will it end up in a "partial purge" enforcing the limit,
or just restrict new messages that won't get added that way?

I couldn't find anything about that in the documentation, nor in any other resources.

Comment: Try it and see! Let us know what you discover.

Comment: Haha, I'd love to know before tbh

Comment: I haven't tried, but I don't think the existing messages in the queue will be affected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that's documented anywhere, but I tried, and currently messages already in the queue aren't affected.

Would still be nice to have an official statement whatsoever on that.